# Android init shell and sub-processes

Tags: android, shell, init

```
#!/system/bin/sh

(
    lCount=0

    while :; do
        sleep 1

        lCount=$(($lCount + 1))

        log -p v -t test "Running test number $lCount"
    done
) & 

lPid=$!

log -p v -t test "Started at $lPid"

exit 0
```

Hi. 
If I put this code into a file on an Android device and execute it manually from a shell, the file will exit perfectly while keeping the sub-process running and printing a logcat once every 1 second. However, if I put this into the init.d folder and reboot the phone, the script will not be released, and depending on the init.d implementation, the phone will not boot.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

(
    lCount=0

    while :; do
        sleep 1

        lCount=$(($lCount + 1))

        log -p v -t test "Running test number $lCount"
    done
) & 

lPid=$!

log -p v -t test "Started at $lPid"

sleep 10

kill -9 $lPid

exit 0
```

If I put this code into init.d instead, the script will be released after the 10 seconds, so the script does continue below the sub-process. So if the script does continue below, why does it not reach the exit command (And continue booting) until after the sub-process has been killed?

Also is there any way to rewrite this so that it does what I want it to do, without adding an additional file to be executed?

Comment: If it is any help, I have located the issue to logwrapper, which is almost always used to execute run-parts which in turn executes the init.d folder. If executed without logwrapper (run-parts only), it works fine. I need a way to force exit logwrapper from within the script.

Comment: Solution: It was quite simple. Just place "killall logwrapper" after starting the sub-process. Both the script and init.d will continue, and the sub-process will run in the background without stalling anything.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
# wait for android os
until [ `pidof com.android.systemui` != "" ]; do
  sleep 1
done;
sleep 35;
```

Script will wait for os first.

Comment: No it will not. Some init.d implementations does not boot the OS until all scripts has been executed. So stalling a script like that will provide a lot of problems for some people. However, like mentioned above, simply killing the logwrapper process fixes this issue.